# How can I make testcafe to copy and use same headers as the actual website?

Tags: header, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

I am running testcafe tests on an authentication page and I can see that testcafe is modifying/removing/adding the headers when sending the requests to the website and this is blocking me to do 2FA on this page

As soon as I got the issue, I tried to do the automation with Selenium just to confirm it is testcafe issue. As selenium doesn't create a proxy to insert the js scripts and automate the website I could do the automation with selenium, but I want to use testcafe as the site is developed in react.

```
        await t.typeText(this.emailInput, config.userEmail)
               .click(this.nextButton)
               .typeText(this.passwordInput, config.userPassword)
               .click(this.nextButton)
               .click(this.otpOption)
               .typeText(this.otpInput, this.token)
               .click(this.signinButton)
       }
```

When clicking on the next button I should have the 2FA form asking for the code, but I got a page saying was not possible to do the authentication (Something wrong happened) and I saw the response code for the BeginAuth endpoint was 222 without any response instead of 200.

The URL is that I am using to authenticate looks like this one:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/`client uuid`/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code%20id_token&response_mode=form_post&client_id=`client uuid`&scope=openid&x-client-Ver=4.0.0

Comment: - When I edit and resend the request I am  able to get 200 and the response body, but I need to remove the headers:
`x-hammerhead|xhr|request-marker: true`
`x-hammerhead|xhr|origin: https://login.microsoftonline.com`

and add the origin one:
`Origin: https://login.microsoftonline.com`

Comment: This may be a bug in TestCafe. We will look for a solution in the context of the [github ticket](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-hammerhead/issues/2052).

Comment: Thanks @Artem I forgot to add the comment here, but yeah it is a bug indeed, I have created the issue in the testcafe hammer-head github project and forgot to add the answer here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testcafe team found out this is a bug on testcafe-hammerhead, they have fixed and it is going to be included in the next release.

https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-hammerhead/issues/2052

For now I am generating the cookie in the automation and sending it in the header.